# xcode iphone emulator doesn't work

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

My iphone simulator just doesn't work anymore,whenever i click on build and run i just get nothing but i can see IOS simulator and all of its related options at the top bar (next to the Apple menu),now if go to the Hardware option and change the device to Ipad Or Iphone(ratina) they  come on the screen with no problem,its just the normal iphone which wont come at all.
 While compiling i dont get any errors or warnings at all ,this problem just started occurring from today morning till last night everything was just fine Xcode version is 3.2.5 .

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your iphone-simulator-folder and verify that the IOS-Simulator.app exists

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/
```

Otherwise update your SDK, this should solve the problem

Comment: inside the iPhoneSimulator.platform/ folder there isn't any  .app file. i already tried reinstalling the whole xcode,it didn't work
and thanks for the ans.